# Crash in sqlite3 while do the sqlite3_prepare_v2

Tags: sqlite, qnx

I'm getting following crash issue on QNX and it's hard to reproduce  and cannot reproduce on Window platform.

```
    *Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0 0x79a7da20 in pcache1EnforceMaxPage () from libClient.so
[Current thread is 35 (pid 1601600 tid 35)]
(gdb) bt
#0 0x79a7da20 in pcache1EnforceMaxPage () from libClient.so
#1 0x79a7e2a0 in sqlite3PagerSetCachesize () from libClient.so
#2 0x79a7ee9c in sqlite3BtreeSetCacheSize () from libClient.so
#3 0x79ade4b0 in sqlite3InitOne () from libClient.so
#4 0x79ade80c in sqlite3Init () from libClient.so
#5 0x79adebb0 in sqlite3ReadSchema () from libClient.so
#6 0x79adf2a4 in sqlite3LocateTable () from libClient.so
#7 0x79adfa98 in selectExpander () from libClient.so
#8 0x79a8065c in sqlite3WalkSelect () from libClient.so
#9 0x79a8b5e0 in sqlite3SelectPrep () from libClient.so
#10 0x79ac6f84 in sqlite3Select () from libClient.so
#11 0x79ad8704 in sqlite3Parser () from libClient.so
#12 0x79adaa40 in sqlite3RunParser () from libClient.so
#13 0x79adc574 in sqlite3Prepare () from libClient.so
#14 0x79adc934 in sqlite3LockAndPrepare () from libClient.so
#15 0x79adcbcc in sqlite3_prepare_v2 () from libClient.so*
```

Comment: Are you sure the crash is because of a bug in SQLite? Then you should report it to the maintainers of SQLite instead. Otherwise, it could be something *you* do wrong, that only manifests itself as a crash in SQLite. Try adding a lot more logging and tracing for all SQLite calls you perform in your code, including showing what values you pass as arguments.